# Update KB4088849 is not applicable to the equipment, Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, windows-update

I've been trying to install the update KB4088889 and the update KB4089510 on Windows Server 2016, but the equipement show message that say: The update is not applicable in this equipement.

I have verified that: the problem occurs with all updates.

I have problems to execute windows updates through independent windows installers.

Comment: If your machine is up to date, or nearly up to date, both the updates you mention in your question genuinely aren't applicable, as already answered.  Saying "all updates" isn't very useful; please give us an example of an update that you think should be applicable but that isn't installing.

Comment: What is the Windows build number?  (Run winver, or just ver if you are using the command line.)  Is KB4480961 one of the updates that is failing to install?

Answer (score 3):

Both updates are from March 2018:

[KB4088889](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4088889)

[KB4089510](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4089510)

Most likely you have newer updates installed (like [KB4478877](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4478877)) and they became replaced by them.

Comment: I have verified that: the problem occurs with all updates

Comment: This is the list of all Updates for Windows 2016: https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=windows+server+2016 Can't you install any update? (For example the updates from yesterday?)